# Area of specific region inside a circle i

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, area

Let S be the circle with centre $(0,0)$, radius $r$ units. The chord $C$ of the circle S subtends an angle of 2π/3 at its center. If R represents the region consisting of all points inside S which are closer to C than to circumference of S, then

(1) What is area of region $R$,  and,

(2) In what ratio does $C$ divide the region $R$ ?

I found the equation of a circle intersecting circle radius $r$ for the chord subtending angle $2\pi/3$ at center we should have

$$ x=\dfrac{r}{2} $$

but don't know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: That is a circle equation...

Comment: I can’t get to the exact answer, but I can tell you  how to get it, in steps, if you’d like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the symmetry, we can consider a upper semicircle
where $DE$ is a half of the chord.

[image]

The chord splits the area in question
in two parts.
Let the points $V_{1,2}$ are the points on the boundary,
for which
the closest points on a circumference are $U_{1,2}$,
and the closest points on a chord are $W_{1,2}$,
and the value of the closed distances are $x_{1,2}$.

Then we can find $x_{1,2}$ in terms of the angles $\phi_{1,2}$ as

\begin{align} 
x_1&=
\tfrac12\,\frac{R(2\cos\phi_1-1)}{\cos\phi_1-1}\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
x_2&=
\tfrac12\,\frac{R(2\cos\phi_2-1)}{\cos\phi_2+1}\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

The coordinates of the point
on the boundary of the first region in therms of $\phi$ are:
\begin{align}
\frac{\tfrac12\,R}{1-\cos\phi}
\cdot(\cos\phi,\, \sin\phi)\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Similarly, the coordinates of the point
on the boundary of the second region in therms of $\phi$ are:
\begin{align}
\frac{\tfrac32\,R}{\cos\phi+1}
\cdot(\cos\phi,\, \sin\phi)\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Now we can find the functions of the boundary curves
\begin{align}
y_1(x)&=
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{R^2+4R\,x}\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
y_2(x)&=
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{9R^2-12R\,x}\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

So the areas can be found as

\begin{align}
S_1&=\int_{-\tfrac14\,R}^{\tfrac12\,R}
y_1(x)\, dx 
=\tfrac{\sqrt3}4\,R^2
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
S_2&=\int_{\tfrac12\,R}^{\tfrac34\,R}
y_2(x)\, dx 
=\tfrac{\sqrt3}{12}\,R^2
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

The total area of the region

\begin{align}
S_{\textsf{tot}}
&=
2S_1+2S_2=
\tfrac23\,\sqrt3\,R^2
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

and the chord splits the area as
\begin{align}
S_1:S_2&=3:1
\tag{10}\label{10}
.
\end{align}

Edit

As @Narasimham pointed out,
both boundary lines are parabolas,
with the focus at the origin
and lines
$x=-\tfrac12\,R$
and
$x=\tfrac32\,R$
as directrices.

Comment: Are points  $ V_1, V_2$ on parabolas?

Comment: @Narasimham: yes, as far as expressions \eqref{5}, \eqref{6} for $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ suggest.

Comment: Then for parabola combination we know area ratio $\dfrac23$ each part so total area straightaway is $\dfrac23 \cdot R\cdot R \sqrt3 = \dfrac{2 R^2}{\sqrt 3}$

Comment: FYI, [here is a diagrammatic demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbjtU.png) that, for any chord, the locus of equidistant points on one side is parabola. The focus is always at the center of the circle, and the directrix is at "radius distance" from the chord.

Answer (score 1):

The circle of interest is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Since there are infinitely many chords which subtend an angle $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ at the center, we might as well assume the chord to be horizontal (slope $0$). By some simple trigonometry , you’ll find that that equation of the chord is $$y=\frac r2$$ Now, let $(a,b)$ with $a^2+b^2\lt 1$ be any point which is closer to $C$ than to the circumference. First, you need to determine the distance of $(a,b)$ from the circumference, which I’ll call $d_1$.

1. Find the equation of the line joining the center of the circle and $(a,b)$.
2. Solve for the point of intersection of this line with the circle (you’ll get two points, of which you must choose the closer one to $(a,b)$).
3. Then, apply the formula for the distance between two points to get $d_1$.

Now, $d_2$ (distance of $(a,b)$ from $C$) is just $$|b-\frac r2|$$ Then to get the locus of all such points, we need $$d_2\lt d_1 \implies d_2^2\lt d_1^2$$ You’ll get a quadratic inequality in $b$ from here, which you have to solve by finding its roots. After that, you’ll get that the value of $b$ must be between two functions, something like $$f(a)\lt b\lt g(a)$$ and this will be the required region $R$. Finding the area is simple from here by integration.

This is a lot of work, but it will work. Hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you draw the circle and the chord, it should become simpler to understand. This is a bit difficult to visualize otherwise.

You could pick any chord that subtends an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ at the center.
For simplicity, let's pick chord (C) with the equation $y = \frac{R}{2}$ where R is the radius of the circle. As you can see, it will subtend an angle of $120^0$ at the center.

Let's pick any point A $(r,\theta)$ inside the circle of radius R.

Now as per problem statement, distance from point A to the line C has to be smaller or equal to the distance from point A to the circumference of the circle.

d = distance from point $A (r, \theta)$ to the line C = $|\frac{R}{2}-rsin\theta|$
r' = distance from point A to the circumference = R-r

As $d \le r', \space |\frac{R}{2}-rsin\theta| \le R-r$.

A few tests for right half of the circle ($x \ge 0$). We can double the area once we find for the right half.

For $r = R, \theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$
For $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}, r \le \frac{R}{4}$
For $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, r \le \frac{3R}{4}$

You can find out that there is discontinuity at $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and two different curves between
$-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{6}$ with Area $A_1$ (say) and $\frac{\pi}{6} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ with Area $A_2$ (say).

$\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/6}\int_{0}^{\frac{R}{2(1-sin\theta)}}r dr d\theta\\\\
A_2 &= \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\frac{3R}{2(1+sin\theta)}}r dr d\theta
\end{align*}$

I hope you can take it from here.

Area of region R = 2($A_1+A_2)$

Ratio in which chord C divides the region R = $\frac{A_1}{A_2}$. It is basically the ratio of area of region R below the chord and above it.